# Laravel 5.2 model static functions use

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5

I probably do not understand how these static functions work.

In my company's project they just create a public static function in any model and then they are using it this way `modelname::functionName()`. I think their models and controllers look similar to mine.

Now, I am training programming at home, I have created a Character model in App directory. Then I tried to use it the same way in CharacterController but it says:

`FatalErrorException in CharacterController.php line 18: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Character' not found`.

For me it looks like Laravel was searching for the static function in controller instead of my model.

My model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use app;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Character extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'character';

    public static function insertCharacterRace($race){
        DB::insert('INSERT INTO `character` VALUES `race` = ?', array($race));
    }

}
```

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;

class CharacterController extends Controller
{


    public function raceSelected($race){
        Character::insertCharacterRace($race);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller change this:

```
use App;
```

To this:

```
use App\Character;
```

Comment: Damn, next error haha: `Class 'App\DB' not found`. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: It doesnt help. Is it possible that I dont have this DB file in my project or something? It is new installed laravel

Comment: You added `use DB;` in model and you still get same error? Alternatively, you can change `DB::` to `\DB::` - in this case you will not need to add `use DB;` clause. BTW, you don't need to use `static`, just use `public function insertCharacterRace($race)`.

Comment: Damn I added it in controller instead of class... Thank you a lot!!